# Python package: pywin32_postinstall returns error

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm trying to run python script as a windows service and then I need to use **pywin32**.

After installation pywin32 via `pip install` I should run `pywin32_postinstall` as `python pywin32_postinstall -install`. I've got this reply and have no idea about this situation anymore:

> 'scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py' not found in metadata at c:\python\lib\site-packages\

[image: result of pywin32_postinstall]

As a result I can't run my service.

Did You meet similar situation or have You any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem!

Don't install via  `pip`

Just need to download suitable file from here: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases

After the installation run `python pywin32_postinstall -install` and no errors will not occur.

Answer (score 1):

try running "python scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install" from the root of the install directory